# Identify allies in event-data via network analysis in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am examining a network of actors involved in civil wars, where each actor is represented as a vertex, and the connections (edges) between them signify instances of conflict or battles. Through network analysis, my goal is to identify allied actors. Initially, I consider actors as allies if they never engage in direct conflict with each other but share common opponents.

However, recognizing that this assumption might not be cautious enough in defining alliances, I additionally aim to adopt a more conservative approach. In this refined criterion, I assert that actors are truly allied only if they not only share two or more common adversaries but also refrain from engaging in battles against each other.

Each network must be build arround a core network, which is identified via the variable `conflict_dset_id`. If an actor has an additional conflict with an external actor, which is not further conected to the core network, this conflict shall be ignored.

Here is a subset of my data, thank you for your help:

```
structure(list(side_a = c("Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Dogon", 
"Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", 
"Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", 
"Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", 
"Dogon", "Dogon", "Dogon", "AQIM", "Jama'atu Ahlis Sunna Lidda'awati wal-Jihad", 
"MUJAO", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ganda Iso", "Ganda Iso", 
"Ganda Iso", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "MAA", "MAA", "MAA", 
"MAA", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA"), side_b = c("Tuareg", "Tuareg", "Tuareg", "Fulani", "Fulani", 
"Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", 
"Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", 
"Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", "Fulani", 
"Fulani", "Fulani", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "MUJAO", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", 
"MUJAO", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "MUJAO", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", 
"MUJAO", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "MUJAO", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", 
"Ansar Dine", "Ansar Dine", "Military faction (Red Berets)", 
"Military faction (Red Berets)", "Military faction (Red Berets)", 
"MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", 
"MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", 
"MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", 
"MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", "MUJAO", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
"AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", 
"Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", 
"al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", 
"al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", 
"al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", 
"al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", "al-Murabitun", 
"CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "CMA", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", 
"FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", 
"FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", "FLM", 
"GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", 
"GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", "GATIA", 
"GATIA", "GATIA", "CM-FPR", "GATIA", "MAA", "CM-FPR", "GATIA", 
"MAA", "CM-FPR", "GATIA", "MAA", "CM-FPR", "GATIA", "MAA", "CM-FPR", 
"GATIA", "MAA"), conflict_dset_id = c(5391, 5391, 5391, 5649, 
5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 
5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 5649, 
5649, 5649, 5650, 5650, 5650, 5651, 5651, 5651, 5651, 5651, 5651, 
5651, 5651, 5651, 5651, 11957, 11957, 11957, 11957, 11957, 11957, 
11957, 11959, 11959, 11959, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 
372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 
372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 
11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 11347, 12589, 12589, 
12589, 12589, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 
13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 
13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 13611, 14730, 14730, 
14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 
14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14730, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 
14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 14733, 
14733, 14733)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are interested in community detection of signed networks?

There are two methods that I developed for doing so, see http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2329 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3083 (the applicability to negative links is not described here, instead, see Chapter 5 here http://hdl.handle.net/2078.1/134615). Code is available for Python (sorry, no R), you can read specifically about the negative links here: https://leidenalg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multiplex.html#negative-links